# The sum of all vectors from two open sets gives an open set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be open subsets of $\Bbb R^k$. Then $A+B = \{\mathbf {x+y}: \mathbf{x}\in A \ and \ \mathbf{y} \in B\}$ is open in $\Bbb R^k$.

I wanted to get an idea of what was going on first, so I drew two open rectangles in $\Bbb R^2$ and added the vectors up. Then I also wrote

$\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2)$

$\mathbf y = (y_1,y_2)$

$\mathbf {x+y} = (x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$.

I can see that for the specific sets I drew and added up, the resulting set is open since $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ are each limited to some set (in this case, that set is an interval) which means that any point in the composed set $(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$ cannot have any $x_i$ or $y_i$ outside of some set of values (in this case, that set of values are the intervals). I hope that makes sense.

Then I can think of two ways to show that a set S is open: Show that its complement is closed (in which case I show that it contains all its limit points), or show that every point in S has an open neighborhood which is a subset of S.

After all this, I don't think I still get a very good idea of what is happening since an open set can also be an annulus or any shape that it seems it would be off to think of the component $x_i's$ and $y_i's$ as being within a certain set doesn't it?

I am not sure how to do this, can somebody please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: $A$ open implies $A + y = \{ x + y : x \in A \}$ open as $A + y$ is simply a copy of $A$ under translation. Now $A + B$ can be viewed as $\bigcup_{y\in B} A + y$, a union of open sets $B + y$. As a result $A + B$ is also open. In fact, this demonstrate $A + B$ is open whenever one of $A$ or $B$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z\in A+B$ so there's   $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $z=a+b$. Now $a\in A$ open so there's $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset A$ and then $B(a+b,r)\subset A+B$. In fact for all $y\in B(a+b,r)$ $y-b\in B(a,r)$ so $y-b\in A$ and then $y\in b+A\subset A+B$. We conclude that $A+B$ is open.

**Remark** We have the same result with just $A$ is open and $B$ is any subset.

Answer (score 0):

There's another good one: a set is open if and only if it is a union of open sets. A refinement of this is that a set is open if and only if it is a union of *basis* open sets (for some chosen basis of the topology).

The set of all open rectangular prisms is a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.