# Prove that the set $X+Y$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider two sets:

$$X=\bigl\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:xy=1\bigr\}$$

$$Y=\bigl\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:|x|\le 1,|y|\le 1\bigr\}.$$

We find that , both the sets are closed. But, is the set $X+Y$ closed?, where $X+Y$ is defined as $X+Y=\bigl\{x+y:x\in X, y\in Y\bigr\}.$We know addition of two open sets is always open but it is NOT true for closed.

When addition of two sets is closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a convergent sequence $a_n\in X+Y$. Each $a_n=x_n+y_n$ for some $x_n\in X$ and $y_n\in Y$. Since $Y$ is compact there is a convergent subsequence $y_{n_k}\to y\in Y$. Therefore $x_{n_k}=a_{n_k}-y_{n_k}$ is convergent. Since $X$ is closed $x_{n_k}\to x$ for some $x\in X$. Therefore $a_{n_k}\to x+y\in X+Y$. Since $a_n$ is convergent, $a_n\to x+y\in X+Y$.

Comment: Nice approach..Thanks...

Comment: @Panja.S. It is a standard use of both compactness and the game with limits when sums are involved. You are surely going to have to use those ideas again.

Comment: Excuse me, could you also give the proof for "if $X,Y$ are open, then so is $X+Y$"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TienKhaPham I am pretty sure that has been asked and answered in this site before. You can try the search box, or post a new question if you can't find it. You end up having to ask a new question you can link it here and I will try to answer it.

Comment: @TienKhaPham See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/993735/203995).

Answer (score 2):

If $K$ is compact and $X$ is closed, then $K+X$ is closed (easy to prove with subsequences, as shown above). However, if $X,Y$ are both closed, then $X+Y$ need not be closed. For example, let $$X=\{2+\frac{1}{2},3+\frac{1}{3},\cdots,n+\frac{1}{n},\cdots\}$$
Then $X+\mathbb{Z}$ is a sum of two closed sets that is not closed, because it has 0 as a limit point.

Comment: So, for this problem compactness of $Y$ implies that $X+Y$ is closed..

Comment: Yes I know. But you also asked: "When is it closed?" And the answer is, $X,Y$ being closed is not sufficient.